# Unable to save data in django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

below mentioned are code complete details I have tried everything and also applied methods available on the internet but the problem still continues. I did not get any errors while submitting the form.

Model:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, default=1)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

View:

```
from .models import Subscriber

def subscriber_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        subscriber = Subscriber(email=email)
        subscriber.save()
    return render(request, 'homepage')
```

urls.py

```
path('', views.subscriber_view, name='subscriber'),
```

base.html

```
{% load static %}

<div class="footer-newsletter">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h4>Join Our Newsletter</h4>
                <p>Tamen quem nulla quae legam multos aute sint culpa legam noster magna</p>
                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'subscriber' %}" id="subscriber" role="form" novalidate="novalidate" >
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <input class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="email" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

from the Django document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create:

create(**kwargs)

A convenience method for creating an object and saving it all in one step. Thus:

```
p = Person.objects.create(first_name="Bruce", last_name="Springsteen")
```

and:

```
p = Person(first_name="Bruce", last_name="Springsteen")
p.save(force_insert=True)
```

are equivalent.

> The force_insert parameter is documented elsewhere, but all it means
> is that a new object will always be created. Normally you won’t need
> to worry about this. However, if your model contains a manual primary
> key value that you set and if that value already exists in the
> database, a call to create() will fail with an IntegrityError since
> primary keys must be unique. Be prepared to handle the exception if
> you are using manual primary keys.

Due to your `Subscriber` model manually setting primary key as so:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
```

You either have to use `create()` or `save(force_insert=True)` for adding new subscriber

Comment: Linh Nguyen Thank you for your answer, I have tried the solutions posted by you also tried checking the link shared but unfortunately, it did not work for me. ```def subscriber_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        #subscriber = Subscriber(email=email)
        subscriber = Subscriber.objects.create(email='email')
        #subscriber.save(force_insert=True)
    return render(request, 'homepage') ````

Comment: @NaushadAhmad have you check in your database to see if it's save? or make sure that the create() method getting run

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for my problem actually everything is fine with the code. I have two views that route to the same URL and it seems that due to conflicts between both the first view runs but not the second one.